# Optimize `from` option value in rails3's mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to change email `from` option in mailer so that when email is received it should be display according to changed value rather than email address.

```
class EnquiryMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "My Test web"

  def reply_email(email,enq_subject,description)
    @reply_description = description
    mail(to: email, subject: "Reply from my test web for Enquiry :: #{enq_subject}")
  end

end
```

but this is displaying email address as from in `From field`
 I want `My Test Web` but not getting this in From field

Answer (score 0):

Try: `default from: "My Test web <email@example.com>"`